# c#: show tooltip on subitem

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, tooltip, subitem

I have a listview, and in one of the columns (not the first) I want to display an error code.

What I haven't been able to do is get the ToolTip to display. I have

```
this.lstList.ShowItemToolTips = true;
...
ListViewItem value = lstList.Items.Add(name, name, 0);
...
if (lstList.Columns.Contains(lstColErrorCode))
{                                
  value.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(value, errorCode.ToString()));
  value.ToolTipText = errorCode.ToString("X");
}
```

I would like to get the hex value of the code to be shown on the tooltip above the decimal value, but it shows above the name.

I haven't been able to get anything I tried to work (like trying to get the coordinates of the subitem). I would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this code works for me

```
ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();

void initMethod()
{
    lstList.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(lstList_MouseMove);//mousemove handler
    this.lstList.ShowItemToolTips = true;            
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(lstList,"");// init the tooltip
    ...
    ListViewItem value = lstList.Items.Add(name, name, 0);
    ...
    if (lstList.Columns.Contains(lstColErrorCode))
    {                                
        ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvs =  value.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(value, errorCode.ToString()));
        lvs.Tag = "mydecimal"; // only the decimal subitem will be tooltiped
    }
}
```

the mousemove event from the listview:

```
void lstList_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = lstList.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
    ListViewHitTestInfo info = lstList.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    if ((item != null) && (info.SubItem != null) && (info.SubItem.Tag!=null) && (info.SubItem.Tag.ToString() == "mydecimal"))
    {
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(lstList,((decimal)info.SubItem.Text).ToString("X"));
    }
    else
    {
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(lstList, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to get this to work - not only the tooltip will not show as I want (even a simple toolTip1.SetToolTip(lstList, "hello");  will not work), but I get tooltips on all items except for the name. Yet the MouseMove works - I had to add an additional check for null for info.SubItem.Tag for the name object, because it was giving an exception  when touched by the mouse... Is there something special about listview, based on the VS version perhaps ?

Comment: no exception either, are you sure that you added all my code lines, try to create a new project then try it may be you can figure out what's wrong

Comment: I have checked, every single item. I will make a small project - tomorrow. Your solution is very logical, it will have o work, I will play with it and find my bug. Thank you.

Comment: Ok ah i've missed a cast (I updated my answer), hope this will work

Comment: I removed the "item" - it was always null. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Using this code, my tooltips are flickering. Even though I stop cursor movement. any ideas ?