# C# - Applying Same Tooltip for all Subitems of a Item in ListView

Tags: c#, listview

I have used the following syntax to apply tooltip on a list view item :-

`listViewSample.ShowItemToolTips = true;
listViewitem.ToolTipText = sItemToolTip;`

here

listViewSample is listview name
listViewitem is listview item name
sItemToolTip is tooltip string

But it shows tooltip on only on first subitem.

How can I show it on all subitems of a item.

Comment: I think the answer is here [c#: show tooltip on subitem][1] 
or here [How to set tooltip for a ListviewSubItem][2]
Please use search.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839323/c-show-tooltip-on-subitem
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069137/how-to-set-tooltip-for-a-listviewsubitem

Comment: Want to do it without any event.